# C++ structs when fields not known beforehand

Tags: c++

I have a C++ program that reads data from a binary/ascii file according to keywords and assign the data to each keyword as vectors.
My preferred data structure to store the data and use it afterwards is structs. The issue is that each file may or may not have some of the keywords and having a comprehensive struct initialized with all possible fields is troublesome as well. My previous research lead to understanding that there is no way to initialize a struct with no fields and then adding fields later. Is this the case? and are there any solutions or alternative data structures that you would recommend?
Thank you in advance.
Example Code:

```
   std::struct s {};
   std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> records;
   //result after reading an asci file: the records map will have
   //keys as strings and values as vectors.
   //What I need is to assign the individual keys and values to 
   //struct s
```

I tried assigning keyword string as field names but it did not work.

Here is a portion of the file contents for those who requested:

> dimens 60 220 85 /
>
> tops 13200*3657 /
>
> dx 1122000*6.096
>
> dy 1122000*3.048
>
> dz 1122000*0.6086

Comment: I'd either try assigning keyword string as field names, or some kind of dictionary lookup.

Comment: Can you please give me an example on assigning keyword string?

Comment: I think you're looking for `std::map`

Comment: "I tried assigning keyword string as field names but it did not work" c++ is statically typed. You can't change field names. How familiar are you with c++?

Comment: Impossible to give you a concise answer without seeing a [mcve] of what you're trying to do.

Comment: _"a binary/ascii file"_ - is a binary file.

Comment: If you *must* keep the structure and field names, I recommend modelling the *structure* with a `std::map<string, string>`.  The first parameter is the field name, the second is the field value (as a string).  You will want to have a `std::pair<string, map<string, string>>` to represent the structure.  The first parameter is the structure name, the second (map) is the structure content.  Looks like you are parsing a language.

Comment: Please post a small portion of the file or input you are parsing.

Comment: Put `records` *inside* of `s`, so it is a member variable.

Answer (score 3):

In C and C++ it's not possible to add struct fields based on user input. In fact, all fields (with name and type) must be known at compile time.

A typical data structure to store key--value pairs in C++ based on user input is [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) (there are others such as [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)). If the field types also vary, one way to solve it is defining your own class for the value, a class which can hold a value of all possible types.